Loading PDFs and querying them once at a time with langchain/Python
I am trying to get some specific information from a group of PDFs using langchain/ChromaDB and the ChatGPT API. I realized that, when I copy a bunch of them and try to pull the information, it doesn´t work well. Thus, rather I need to do it once at a time: load a document from the folder, query it and getting the answer that I want, and then adding another, querying it, and so on. Could you please throw some hints in order to to so?
I have the following code to create the dataset:
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.schema import Document
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
from langchain.document_loaders.pdf import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
import shutil
from openai import OpenAI
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "MyKey"

CHROMA_PATH = "chroma"
DATA_PATH = "docs"

def main():
    generate_data_store()

def generate_data_store():
    documents = load_documents()
    chunks = split_documents(documents)
    save_to_chroma(chunks)

def load_documents():
    document_loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH)
    return document_loader.load()

def split_documents(documents: list[Document]):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size=800,
        chunk_overlap=80,
        length_function=len,
        is_separator_regex=False,
    )
    return text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

def save_to_chroma(chunks: list[Document]):
    # Clear out the database first.
    if os.path.exists(CHROMA_PATH):
        shutil.rmtree(CHROMA_PATH)

    # Create a new DB from the documents.
    db = Chroma.from_documents(
        chunks, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH
    )
    db.persist()
    print(f"Saved {len(chunks)} chunks to {CHROMA_PATH}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

And this, to make the query:
import argparse
from dataclasses import dataclass
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

from openai import OpenAI
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "MyKey"

CHROMA_PATH = "chroma"

PROMPT_TEMPLATE = """
Answer the question based only on the following context:

{context}

---

Answer the question based on the above context: {question}
"""


def main():
    # Create CLI.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("query_text", type=str, help="The query text.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    query_text = args.query_text

    # Prepare the DB.
    embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    db = Chroma(persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH, embedding_function=embedding_function)

    # Search the DB.
    results = db.similarity_search_with_relevance_scores(query_text, k=3)
    if len(results) == 0 or results[0][1] < 0.7:
        print(f"Unable to find matching results.")
        return

    context_text = "\n\n---\n\n".join([doc.page_content for doc, _score in results])
    prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(PROMPT_TEMPLATE)
    prompt = prompt_template.format(context=context_text, question=query_text)
    print(prompt)

    model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o", temperature=0.0)
    response_text = model.predict(prompt)

    sources = [doc.metadata.get("source", None) for doc, _score in results]
    formatted_response = f"Response: {response_text}\nSources: {sources}"
    print(context_text)
    print(formatted_response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried to copy a bunch of PDFs and querying them about an specific topic in each of them. It didn't work. Now I want to do it sequentially: incorporate a PDF once at time into the ChromaDB, query it, and getting the right info, and so on with the remaining PDFs.
